# How to call s3 bucket from ECS container via aws sdk (java) by using IAM role

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to read a  file from s3 bucket from ECS container by using aws sdk. What are the best option available?. I tried initializing aws client with default aws creds give but that did not work. I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/ec2-iam-roles.html   but InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider is also depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet to create an object and put the detail of the error you are getting

```
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(<>).build();
```